# How to alert() in Go to show messagebox

Tags: go, messagebox

In javascript, if we want to show pop up messagebox with custom message in browser, we can use `alert("message")` function.

How to do it in `Go`?

Comment: alert is only browser core function where you want to use in golang

Comment: `print` is the most basic debug-meant output function for Go. However, I suggest using the functions within the `fmt` package for IO. eg `fmt.Printf`

Comment: Where do you expect this "pop up" to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log in go with the [log](https://golang.org/pkg/log/) package or the [fmt](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package, using log.Printf or log.Println for example.

Answer (score 7):

I made a very simple package to do this.

There are other packages (like [sqweek's](https://github.com/sqweek/dialog)) with more features, but I was just after something simple for startup errors and didn't want to add compile time requirements like cgo, gtk etc.

Download it with `go get github.com/tawesoft/golib/v2`

Then use it like this:

```
package main

import "github.com/tawesoft/golib/v2/dialog"

func main() {
    dialog.Alert("Message")
    dialog.Alert("There are %d lights", 4)
}
```

Caveats:

- Only supports windows and linux at the moment ([contribute](https://github.com/tawesoft/golib))

[Documentation is here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tawesoft/golib/v2/dialog) - there's a few extras like a "Open"/"Save As" file picker.

**Update**

I've seen a few people misusing this when writing server-side code. This messagebox *will only appear on the computer running the Go program*. If you are displaying a HTML page and want a messagebox to show up on the user's computer, you need to output JavaScript code for an alert on the page the user is visiting instead!

Comment: Wasn't looking for exactly what OP was looking for but this is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: Another high quality package for boxes is zenity : https://github.com/ncruces/zenity#readme

Answer (score 3):

For the `Windows` operating system, you can use `user32.dll` to help you, like below.

```
package main

import ("fmt";"syscall";"unsafe")

func main() {
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxw
    var user32DLL = syscall.NewLazyDLL("user32.dll")
    var procMessageBox = user32DLL.NewProc("MessageBoxW") // Return value: Type int
    const (
        MB_OK          = 0x00000000
        MB_OKCANCEL    = 0x00000001
        MB_YESNO       = 0x00000004
        MB_YESNOCANCEL = 0x00000003

        MB_APPLMODAL   = 0x00000000
        MB_SYSTEMMODAL = 0x00001000
        MB_TASKMODAL   = 0x00002000

        MB_ICONSTOP        = 0x00000010
        MB_ICONQUESTION    = 0x00000020
        MB_ICONWARNING     = 0x00000030
        MB_ICONINFORMATION = 0x00000040
    )

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxw#return-value
    const (
        IDCANCEL = 2
        IDYES    = 6
        IDNO     = 7
    )
    lpCaption, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString("Done Title")      // LPCWSTR
    lpText, _ := syscall.UTF16PtrFromString("This test is Done.") // LPCWSTR

    /*
        // LazyProc will call SyscallN eventually, so I will suggest you use SyscallN instead of LazyProc.Call (faster)
        clickBtnValue, _, _ := procMessageBox.Call(uintptr(0x00),
            uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(lpText)),
            uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(lpCaption)),
            MB_YESNOCANCEL)
    */

    clickBtnValue, _, _ := syscall.SyscallN(procMessageBox.Addr(),
        0,
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(lpText)),
        uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(lpCaption)),
        MB_YESNOCANCEL|
            MB_ICONQUESTION| // You can also choose an icon you like.
            MB_SYSTEMMODAL, // Let the window TOPMOST.
    )

    if clickBtnValue == IDYES {
        fmt.Printf("select Yes")
    }
}
```

- [MessageBoxW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxw)
- [IDYES, IDNO, ...](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxw#return-value)

Comment: Good! One question: how can I force the popup to be the focused window (ex. requires attention)? While focusing another program this will appear only in the application bar...

Comment: Hi @Bellisario , I have updated the answer. I think the attribute "MB_SYSTEMMODAL" may be helpful to you.

Comment: This is a really good example of using the windows API through loading a DLL at runtime, but you can also use /x/sys/windows to do this a bit more simply. It defines a lot of the constants like MB_OK for you, too https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sys/windows#MessageBox