# MessageBox User32.dll, how to add links (Go programming language)

Tags: windows, go, dll, hyperlink, user32

I discovered how to create a simple MessageBox in Go using this Stackoverflow answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71919136/14997578

This uses the user32 Windows DLL to create it.

The problem is that now I need to add a link to it, witch you can click, obviously.
I tried writing the link like normal text but it outputs normal text, too.

Is there a way I can add links to user32.dll MessageBox?

Answer (score 1):

A MessageBox only supports a icon and plain text.

Use a [Task dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/task-dialogs-overview) ([ComCtl v6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37016803/3501)) and the `TDF_ENABLE_HYPERLINKS` flag. `TaskDialogIndirect` is ordinal 345.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found a Go task dialog example [here](https://github.com/balibuild/tunnelssh/blob/2d05422a00b06a134bc985b72c86a6cb62af7dda/cmd/ssh-askpass/windows.go#L184) but I'm not sure how to use, because I don't know how to use DLLs.
I upvoted your answer but I need a real Go implementation, so, let's see if someone posts it...